# The with insert in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$m = clearData($_POST['msg']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages(message,message_from)
  VALUES('$m','$_SESSION['id']')";
```

I get an error on insert and I not found:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

Comment: escape your input for god's sake! mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13935532/541091 for the specific syntax problem.

Comment: But much more importantly, read over [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use arrays like that when defining the text. Wrap it in Curly Brackets:

```
$m = clearData($_POST['msg']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages(message,message_from) VALUES( '$m','{$_SESSION['id']}')";
```

Or:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO messages(message,message_from) VALUES( '%s','%d')",
  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']),
  $_SESSION['id']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$m = mysqli_real_escape_string(clearData($_POST['msg'])); // escape or whatever.  
$sessionId = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']); // or whatever, just escape the field

$sql = "INSERT INTO messages(message,message_from) VALUES( '{$m}','{$sessionId}')";
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to wrap the strings,only arrays. http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/10/0

Comment: @Twisty though he doesn't need to, it can look cleaner and easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your single quotes are nested in :

```
'$_SESSION['id']'
```

Replace it with :

```
"INSERT INTO messages(message,message_from)VALUES('$m','".$_SESSION['id']."')"
```